# How do you install extension vsix files to TFS 2015 (Update 3)?

Tags: plugins, tfs-2015

I downloaded calendar extension file, but cannot figure how TFS uploads the file?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.team-calendar

Can you upload from UI?

Comment: Follow this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions#upload-to-team-foundation-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before uploading extensions, you must be a member of the Team Foundation Administrators group with **Edit instance-level information** permissions for the Team Foundation Server where you want to upload extensions.

1. Go to your TFS home page `(http://{server}:8080/tfs/)`.
2. Browse for your downloaded TFS extensions `(http://{server}:8080/tfs/_gallery)`.

[image]

3. Manage your extensions.

[image]

4. Upload the extension that you downloaded.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the details, easy to follow!

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow a few links from the administration pages, but basically it's at http://server:8080/tfs/_gallery/manage